# How can i convert json array in string format into array[]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am rendering this data in a table, how can I convert Cuisine_style
into array???

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Martine of Martine's Table",
    "City": "Amsterdam",
    "Cuisine_Style": "['French', 'Dutch', 'European']",
    "Ranking": 1,
    "Rating": 5,
    "Number of Reviews": 136
  },
  {
    "Name": "De Silveren Spiegel",
    "City": "Amsterdam",
    "Cuisine_Style": "['Dutch', 'European', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Gluten Free Options']",
    "Ranking": 2,
    "Rating": 4.5,
    "Number of Reviews": 812
  }
]
```

Comment: what array language do you use?

Comment: *Not easily* is the most straight forward answer here. How'd you get the data into this format in the first place?

Comment: Is there no way you could fix the JSON encoding part instead?

Comment: @GilangPratama javascript

Comment: `JSON.parse("['Dutch', 'European', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Gluten Free Options']".split("'").join("\""))`  Not very pretty, so I don't dare making it an answer.

Comment: @ippi 1) Why not `.replace` instead of splitting and joining?! 2) We do not know whether those substrings might contain quotes themselves and hence how safe it is to blindly replace quotes…

Comment: @deceze I get the impression OP isn't writing mission-critical code here.

Comment: @Christian It should still *work*…

Comment: @deceze Eh, it does, for all the examples he listed even, no raw single quotes. Probably good to just lazily replace, if OP wants to add to their question they can.

Comment: @Christian Sure… Of course, the real solution is probably to handle the data slightly differently someplace upstream so you don't need to solve this problem in the first place… ‍♂️

Comment: @deceze Yeah, I literally have no idea how you get non-JSON JSON like he posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is not an endorsement of bad object serialization

If you absolutely must consume the data in this format, you can replace the single quotes with double quotes to make them JSON-compliant:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Name": "Martine of Martine's Table",
    "City": "Amsterdam",
    "Cuisine_Style": "['French', 'Dutch', 'European']",
    "Ranking": 1,
    "Rating": 5,
    "Number of Reviews": 136
  },
  {
    "Name": "De Silveren Spiegel",
    "City": "Amsterdam",
    "Cuisine_Style": "['Dutch', 'European', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Gluten Free Options']",
    "Ranking": 2,
    "Rating": 4.5,
    "Number of Reviews": 812
  }
];

for (const item of data)
    item['Cuisine_Style'] = JSON.parse(item['Cuisine_Style'].replace(/'/g, '"'));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```js
var arr_data = [{
    "Name": "Martine of Martine's Table",
    "City": "Amsterdam",
    "Cuisine_Style": "['French', 'Dutch', 'European']",
    "Ranking": 1,
    "Rating": 5,
    "Number of Reviews": 136
  },
  {
    "Name": "De Silveren Spiegel",
    "City": "Amsterdam",
    "Cuisine_Style": "['Dutch', 'European', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Gluten Free Options']",
    "Ranking": 2,
    "Rating": 4.5,
    "Number of Reviews": 812
  }
];
var y = JSON.stringify(arr_data);
var x = y.toString();

console.log(x);
```

Comment: If the array is one dimensional array you can string array with .toString() function. but if array is multi-dimensional you can use JSON.stringify()